# java in windows2003 can not load jar correctly

Tags: java

I have a flume agent run on different servers.It can work in centos and windows 2008.
  But when I run it in windows 2003,It got errors.
  All point in the path is replaced to '/',what's wrong with it?I guess that which windows variable is not be correct set?

Thanks.
[image: error msg]

Answer (score 0):

When you set your agnet using bin/flume-ng.... make sure to specify the file where the agent configuration is.

--conf-file flume_Agent.conf -> -f conf/flume_Agent.conf